# Disable calls and SMS and use only mobile data with active SIM card

Tags: internet, mobile-data, call-screening, sms-blocking, sony-xperia-z1

I have a Sony Xperia Z1 packed with Android 4.3 Jelly Bean. I'm interested if it's possible to setup my phone to not receive any phone calls or SMS.

I would like to use my Internet connection only, and I don't mean WiFi - my mobile ISP connection from the SIM card.

Is this possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 7):

There is one hack by which you can block your incoming calls.

Go to `Settings` -> `Call settings` -> `Call forwarding`
Now Click on `Always forward` and enable it to forward the calls to a wrong number.
This will ensure that calls will not come to you and the caller get the tone that call is being forwarded and number is wrong.

You can disable `Call forwarding` anytime you want.

Hope this will help.

Comment: I have the same question, but I have to be able to enable and disable phone/sms, quickly and effortlessly, while commuting (so Google Maps keeps working). So digging through settings each time isn't going to dig it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about SMS but you can block all incoming calls.

Just go to Settings > Call Settings (under "Device") > Call Blocking and select your preferred settings i.e. Block incoming calls.

Comment: Sorry under call settings there is call blocking that is what you need to click on