# How to block all messages and calls from any numbers?

Tags: samsung, call-screening, sms-blocking

I want to block all kinds of messages and calls from any numbers that come into my tablet (Samsung Galaxy Tab S2, rooted), but I still want to have mobile data available. What should I do?

Comment: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/65649/disable-calls-and-sms-and-use-only-mobile-data-with-active-sim-card

Comment: The question you gave me doesn't mention about SMS blocking. Any idea?

Comment: Use blacklist app that mentioned here : http://droidlessons.com/how-to-block-unwanted-calls-text-messages-on-android/